# How to change color in a column in lazyhighcharts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, lazy-high-charts

I am using LazyHighCharts in rails 3. My requirement is to show different color in a column.
when i use 
            series = {
              :type=> 'bar',
              :name=> [],
              :data=> @rooms,
          :color=> 'pink'
           }
it displays whole column in pink color. Suppose i have 5 rows in a column and i want to show first row in pink color and the rest four row in green color. can anyone suggest me solution for this.
thnks

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you have resolved this issue, but this is how i resolved it.

```
#Controller before set data to the series option
data = []
your_array.each do |t|
       data << {:y=>t.value, :color=>"#"+("%06x" % (rand * 0xffffff))}
end

then set data to series option
f.series({:name=>"Subcurso", :data=>data} )
```